# Program to redirect all queries

Tags: redirect

i dont know how to really describe my problem, but i will give it a shot.

I want that all queries (e.g. an application tries to reach/send something to: 68.655.21.1:8421). I want that i am able to catch this and reply with my own answer.

So if any programm tries to send data to any domain or IP it will get redirected to my localhost, or any other IP.

Sorry for this bad description, it is hard for me to find the right words.

I hope for a good answer =)

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You could try a tool like [Fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/).

Answer (score 0):

look at your [HOSTS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hosts_%28file%29) file

look into something like [WinPCap](http://www.winpcap.org/)

look at external [socks proxies](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOCKS)

look at [fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/) if you only want to capture http traffic